# Разрешение на постинг через Facebook API

Tags: авторизация, facebook, facebook-api

Настраивал Facebook API и все получилось. Получать данные можно без проблем. Но мне необходимо настроить автопостинг новостей в Page.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что для такого автопостинга мне необходимо пройти Items in Review?

Если да, то что пишется в таких полях как: "Please provide step-by-step instructions in English that show how to access Facebook Login." Как я получал доступ к API пошагово? это что вообще? У них самих на сайте висит инструкция Как и они просят еще раз написать? И просят ровно 4 скриншота использования API. Мне фото php скрипта присылать? :) Это ведь не приложение на телефон, а сайт, где функция автопостинга спрятана глубоко в код.

Там указано, что эти поля обязательны для заполнения. Люди на полном серьезе это заполняют? Кто сталкивался с этим - как вы получали доступ к "publish_pages" или к тем items, которые требуют review?

Answer (score 1):

> Please provide step-by-step instructions in English that show how to access Facebook Login

При модерации сотрудникам Facebook нужно будет убедиться, что API используется правильно. Чтобы облегчить эту задачу, Вы должны указать, "куда тыкать", чтобы авторизоваться через Facebook Login

> И просят ровно 4 скриншота использования API. Мне фото php скрипта присылать?

Можно сказать и так. Но не исходного кода, а результата его выполнения. Другими словами, скриншоты сайта в браузере